# Having PyQt app controlling all. How use reactor?

Tags: python, django, twisted, pyqt4, reactor

I've a django application, served via Twisted, which also serves ohter services (three sockets, mainly).

I need to have it working under windows, and I decide to write a PyQt4 application which acts quite like **Apache Service Monitor** for windows.

I was not able to connect twisted reactor to pyqt application reactor, so any hint on this will be welcome too.

Now I've this kind of architecture:

- **QMainWindow** which, in __ init __() has the log.addObserver(callBack) function, and the widget.
- **Twisted initializer** class which extends **QtCore.QThread** and works in a different thread.
- **the django app** which runs over Twisted.

I need to understand how to run the reactor, becouse calling reactor.start() from **QtCore.QThread** works not at all, giving me:

```
exceptions.ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Also I'm asking your opinion on the design of applications, does it makes sense for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your design but what I can say is that you need to use only one reactor in an application. The reactor is the main (event) loop of the application. And, I think, this reactor should be the [QTReactor](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/QTReactor) in your case.

Comment: That's true, but I have not been able to have it running.

Comment: One thing is that you should use `reactor.run()` to start the reactor (and not `reactor.start()`. Are you able to run the *QT reactor demo* from the link I have post? If yes, I would say, base your design from this demo.

Comment: That demo is for qt3, not for qt4, sadly.

Comment: That github project is the right way (imho). I'll follow the hint.